# how to set a cookie from a javascript ala Facebook or similar

Tags: javascript, facebook

how to set a cookie in order to live throughout any site you visit and can detect that you are loggedin in that website...

kind alike as the facebook Connect that if you install it it recognizes that you have previously loggedin in FB

what the direction should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are persistent cookies. These are cookies with an expiry. And if you're going to be reading them across subdomains, you should also specify a domain. Here's a small nudge in the right direction:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

Comment: but is the persistent cookie like the regular cookie? if i set it form site1.com is it retrievable if i'm visiting site2.com?

Comment: No, never across different domains. You can use different subdomains on a common domain. You can set it from foo.example.com and access it from bar.example.com if you set the path as example.com.

Comment: my question was, how facebook is able to detect if a user had loggedin and recognize it from another website that's using their api? what's the principle behind that?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how Facebook does it, but the general principle probably revolves around JSONP -- the loading of a `<script>` from facebook.com which causes a callback to be called with the authentication status of the user.